# Method of Characteristics for $(1+x^2)u_x+2u_y=y\cdot(1+u^2)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Suppose I had a problem like

$$(1+x^2)u_x+2u_y=y\cdot(1+u^2),\;\; u(1,y)=1$$

This is of the form 
$$a(x,y)u_x+b(x,y)u_y+c(x,y,u)$$
So I would use the *Method of Characteristics*:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=(1+x^2)\implies x=\tan(t+c_1)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2\implies y=2t+c_2$$

Using the initial condition we get that
$$t=\tan^{-1}x -1,\;\; c_2=y-2\tan^{-1}(x)+2$$
Where I'm having a bit of an issues is with the $du/dt$ term.  Would I set it up like 
$$\frac{du}{dt}=(2t+c_2)(1+u^2)\implies u=\tan(t^2+c_2t+c_3)?$$
Then sub in the $c_2$ to get 
$$u=\tan\left[t^2+(y-2\tan^{-1}x+2)t+c_3)\right]?$$
Then use the initial condition again to get that 
$$u(1,y)=\tan\left[t^2+(y-2\tan^{-1}(1)+2)t+c_3)\right]$$
and solve for c_3?

Comment: I think the problem is a bit easier if you think of it as an IVP in one variable or the other. If $x$ is the "time" variable then you have $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{1+x^2}$ so $y=2\arctan(x)+C$ along the characteristics. There you will have $\frac{du}{dx}$ (total derivative) equal to $\frac{y(1+u^2)}{1+x^2}=\frac{(2 \arctan(x)+C)(1+u^2)}{1+x^2}$. This is now a separable ODE for $u$.

Comment: @Ian I'm just trying to get a grasp on the method of characteristics by working out what seems to be a fairly straight forward problem.  But thanks for the clarity!

Comment: I understand, I'm just trying to get an understanding for why you are introducing the auxiliary variable $t$ instead of treating $x$ as a function of $y$ or vice versa.

Comment: @Ian I was just trying a method in the book I'm using.  They parameterized the coordinates with $t$.

Comment: OK. In that case, if you are following a parametric curve $(x(t),y(t))$ then $\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$. So along a curve satisfying $\frac{dx}{dt}=1+x^2$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=2$ you have $\frac{du}{dt}=y(1+u^2)=(2t+c_1)(1+u^2)$. You solve this separable ODE to get $u$ as a function of $t$, I guess you have $\arctan(u(t))=t^2+c_1t+c_2$ so $u(t)=\tan(t^2+c_1t+c_2)$.

Comment: Now to find $u(x,y)$ you need to find 1. which characteristic curve it lies on (i.e. which $(x_0,y_0)$ you need to use) and 2. which time you see the point $(x,y)$ on that curve. You also need to be careful to ensure that the point only lies on one characteristic. So the characteristic curves look like $x=\tan(t+c_3),y=2t+c_1$. Plug in $x(0)=x_0,y(0)=y_0$ to get $c_3=\arctan(x_0),c_1=y_0$.  So you need to find $(x_0,y_0,t)$ satisfying $x=\tan(t+\arctan(x_0)),y=2t+y_0$ given $(x,y)$. This is two equations in three unknowns so it seems somewhat non-obvious how to solve it uniquely...

Comment: @Ian I have one more question, if you don't mind.  Suppose that I get $u$ down to, say, $u(x,y)=tan(cx+f(y))$ with the initial condition $u(1,y)=\tan(y)$.  Then would my solution end up being $u(x,y)=\tan(y)$?

Comment: I don't know what $f(y)$ is to be able to tell.

Comment: @Ian What if we just say it's some arbitrary function.  When I plug in $1$ I get that $u(1,y)=\tan(c+f(y))=\tan(y)$, and so $c+f(y)=y$, and so $f(y)=y-c$ and so $u(x,y)=\tan(cx+y-c)$.  I'm sorry if none of this makes sense, I'm just trying to get my bearing with some of these ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40439/discussion-between-pretzelman-and-ian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1+x^2)u_x+2u_y=y\cdot(1+u^2),\qquad u(1,y)=1$$

Another approach to compare to what was discussed in the comments :

Change of function : $u(x,y)=\tan\left(U(x,y)\right)  \quad\to\quad \begin{cases} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=(1+u^2)\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=(1+u^2)\frac{\partial U}{\partial y} \end{cases}$

$$(1+x^2)U_x+2U_y=y$$
with condition : $u(1,y)=1=\tan\left(U(1,y)\right)  \quad\to\quad U(1,y)=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi$

Change of variable : $\begin{cases}x=\tan(X) \\ U(x,y)=V(X,y)\end{cases}$ $\quad\to\quad (1+x^2)\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial X}$

$$V_X+2V_y=y$$
Condition : $U(1,y)=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi=V\left((\frac{\pi}{4}+m\pi),y\right)$

$\frac{1}{4}y^2$ is a particular solution

Change of function : $V(X,y)=\frac{1}{4}y^2+W(X,y)$
$$W_X+2W_y=0$$
Condition : $\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi=\frac{1}{4}y^2+W\left((\frac{\pi}{4}+m\pi),y\right)$

With the method of characteristics, the characteristic equations are :

$$\frac{dX}{1}=\frac{dy}{2}=\frac{dW}{0}$$
From $\frac{dX}{1}=\frac{dy}{2}$ the first characteristic curve : $\quad 2X-y=c_1$

From $dW=0$ the second characteristic curve : $W=c_2$

General solution on implicit form : $\Phi(2X-y\:,\: W)=0$ any differentiable function $\Phi$ of two variables.

Solving the implicit equation for the second variable $\quad\to\quad W=F(2X-y)\quad$ any differentiable function $F$.

The condition :  $\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi= \frac{1}{4}y^2+F\left(2(\frac{\pi}{4}+m\pi)-y\right)$ determines the function $F$ : 
$$F(Y)=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi- \frac{1}{4}\left(-Y+\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi\right)^2$$

$$W=F(2X-y)=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi- \frac{1}{4}\left(-(2X-y)+\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi\right)^2$$

$$V(X,y)=\frac{1}{4}y^2+W(X,y)=\frac{1}{4}y^2+\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi- \frac{1}{4}\left(-(2X-y)+\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi\right)^2$$

$$U(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}y^2+\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi- \frac{1}{4}\left(-(2\tan^{-1}(x)-y)+\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi\right)^2$$

$$u(x,y)=\tan\left(\frac{1}{4}y^2+\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi- \frac{1}{4}\left(-(2\tan^{-1}(x)-y)+\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi\right)^2 \right)$$
After simplification :
$$u(x,y)=\tan\left(\frac{y^2+\pi-\left(y-2\tan^{-1}(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}+2m\pi\right)^2}{4} \right)$$
any integer $m$.